# Relations between correlation function and commutators of two observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, correlation-functions

In quantum theory (QFT or Quantum statistical mechanics), are correlation of two observable related to their commutator? Is there any explicit bound of the correlation by the norm of the commutator? It's clear from definition that some relation must be there. I know correlation can mean different things in different areas, but I welcome answers for various sense of the word (ground state, Gibbs or KMS states).

Comment: You mean besides [HUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle)?

Comment: HUP would certainly be a relation, however, it's way too general and not strong enough. There has to be stronger relations when the correlation is taken over the ground state or Gibbs state.

Comment: If you are defining correlation as defined in statistics (i.e. $\text{Corr}(A,B)=\text{Cov}(A,B)/\sigma_A \sigma_B$) the Robertson-Schrödinger uncertainty relations may lead you to what you're looking for (if $A$ and $B$ dont commute). You can obtain the result that the correlation is bounded above by $\sqrt{1 - \frac{\langle[A,B]\rangle}{2\sigma_A\sigma_B}^2}\leq 1$. If this is what you need I can type it neatly as an answer (edit: remember since they don't commute, we need the second moment as $\frac12 \{A,B\}$)

Comment: Btw the square in the square root is around the whole second term not just the numerator in case it is unclear cos I cannot edit now